# Facebook Graph API - How to get Gender from Public Profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to retrieve the gender from a Facebook user from his public profile via Facebook Graph API.

Unfortunately it is not always working. See these examples:

working:
https://graph.facebook.com/1423993568

```
{
   "id": "1423993568",
   "gender": "male",
   ...
}
```

not working:
https://graph.facebook.com/10152133878666403

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

But when I open the user id directly via web, it works, and I can even see the gender. (Go to "About/Contact and Basic Info") I am logged in with my personal account and not a friend of this user!
http://www.facebook.com/10152133878666403

What is the problem? Is it a problem with the request or a security feature from Facebook?

**UPDATE:**

I can do a workaround like this, but only if I am logged in with my browser:

Take the app_scoped_user_id and get the Facebook username from the redirect URL, when opening this request:

```
http://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/10152133878666403
  --> https://www.facebook.com/shiffoni
  --> https://graph.facebook.com/shiffoni
```

returns:

```
{
   "id": "669926402",
   "first_name": "Shiffoni",
   "gender": "female",
   "last_name": "Leonhardt",
   "locale": "de_DE",
   "name": "Shiffoni Leonhardt",
   "username": "shiffoni"
}
```

Any other ideas to get the gender, real userId, or nickname?

Comment: 10152133878666403 is an app scoped user id. You need to supply a user access token for the same app as the app that got that app scoped user id

Comment: Just because something is public on Facebook.com doesn't mean it is public to all apps

Comment: Ok, understand. - Is there any way how i can translate the app scoped user id to a normal user id? - Which permissions do I need to retrieve the public information?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already answered in the comments by a Facebook employee, it is simply not possible, because it is not supported to get the 'gender' or the real Facebook user id.

Possible workarounds:

- use gender api (e.g. [genderize.io](http://genderize.io)) to retrieve gender based on first
  name.
- scrape the gender information from the Facebook (need to be
  logged in via web) from the user about page.

Answer (score 2):

Best Way to check it using facebook graph api under develoers.facebook.com => tools & support =>Graph API Explorer.

```
$fb = new Facebook(array(
 'appId'  => $app_id,
  'secret' => $app_secret,
  'cookie' => true
));

$fbuser=$fb->api('/me/friends?fields=id,name,gender');
```

it will give an array of your all friends with name & gender, you can loop through and put a condition inside the loop for separating the male & female friends.

Hope it helps

for more info read this article

[Getting Facebook Friends with Gender](http://www.howtobloger.com/2013/10/getting-facebook-friends-by-gender.html)

Answer (score 2):

User gender is returned only with API version v1.0. Unfortunately v1.0 is available until April 30, 2015 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog. http://www.name-gender.com/ is also a quite good api to check gender.

Answer (score -1):

Form what i understand it is not possible only from graph api v3, because in 2.12 i still do able to get gender

Answer (score -2):

it is not possible in facebook to get the gender of the profile but you can split the first name and send request to https://genderapi.io

> https://genderapi.io/api/?name=mike

`{"name":"mike", "q":"mike", "gender":"male", "total_names":8336, "probability":99}`